# How do I check if a swf file loaded correctly since put_Movie always returns S_OK?

Tags: c++, flash, com

I am using the latest flash player and have a swf file served locally from my dev machine.  In one container test app I am able to play the swf and make calls to it, but in my "Real" application the same code path results in com errors (basically it looks like the swf isn;' loading properly)

Additionally this is made more challenging because no matter what nonsense I put in the call to put_Movie() the return is ALWAYS S_OK.  This is confusing.

How am I supposed to determine if the swf file loaded and is working?

As a follow-on, what would cause a swf file (the same one) not to load in a different app?  The code paths are the same (from what I can tell).

Obviousl something is going on, but I am not sure what.

So, I guess 2 questions

- How to know when swf file doesn't load right
- Why might it fail in a different container application?

I am using ATL in Visual studio 2008, latest flash, MS Vista

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,  it seems that if I listen for the DISPID_READYSTATECHANGE events then that helps me.

A value of '4' seems to indicate it is ready to accept method calls.

Comment: What about the answer to your second question? Sometimes it just fails to load the swf with no obvious reason and no error return code in my application.

Comment: I think the answer to that was timing and event handling.  It was so long ago I really don't remember.